# How to prevent PHP update from creating generic config file and changing permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, php, yum

We use suPHP and whenever our php packages are updated, a new php.conf file is dropped into the apache config folder (/etc/httpd/conf.d) and this causes 500 error's as it configures the handler for php scripts to be the standard php interpreter (AddHandler php5-script .php) instead of suphp. When this happens we have to manually delete php.conf and restart Apache.

In addition the PHP package also changes the ownership of /var/lib/php/sessions to root:apache and we need it to be root:suphpgroup.

Any ideas on how we can avoid these two issues caused by every PHP update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a blank `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and leave it there. The RPM packages will not overwrite it, since it's changed from the original distributed file; instead they'll create it as `php.conf.rpmnew` which Apache will ignore, and you can go clean up later at your leisure.

Comment: Thanks, great solution, I should have remembered that! Any idea about the permission issue on the sessions folder?

Comment: There's no great solution for that. The best idea I can come up with is to put your sessions somewhere else.